# md-datepicker shows scrollbar on the side on Edge and IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker, angular-material

I am using the standard md-datepicker on my page. Its working fine on all browsers but on IE11 and Edge, theres a weird scrollbar displayed on the right.

Please find the screenshot below.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDatepicker" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <md-datepicker 
      ng-model = "myDate" 
      md-placeholder = "Enter date" md-hide-icons="triangle">
    </md-datepicker>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.myDate = "";
this.isOpen = false;
```

CSS:

```
.md-default-theme .md-datepicker-input-container, .md-datepicker-input-container {
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.md-default-theme .md-datepicker-input, .md-datepicker-input {
  color: #1797c0;
}

#myDatepicker .md-datepicker-calendar-icon {
  color: #1797c0;
}
```

Also there's an orange line underneath the placeholder which I have tried changing to white in the CSS above - not sure why its not being applied?

Link - [IE 11 - scrollbar on the right of datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JbfO.png)

Link - [Edge - scrollbar on the right of datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXyWb.png)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an issue with the height of md-datepicker for some reason, it's possible that adding `overflow: hidden;` to md-datepicker CSS could resolve. Without seeing it in JSFiddle or similar, it's difficult to tell for sure.

If you inspect the page in Chrome using Dev Tools can you see a property that has the orange color? It's likely something built into the default theme that you're not over-riding or changing correctly. I think you might have to apply a border color to `.md-input-container` and `.md-input`